# Application.ScreenUpdating = False not working switching between Excel sheets or workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

The function `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is not working whenever switching between worksheets or workbooks in Excel. This function alone worked fine in Excel 2010, but doesn't work in later versions from what I can tell. I am now using the office 365 desktop version of excel. In these later versions, the command only prevents updating when selecting cells or doing things within a specific worksheet, but for my purposes I need a form to pull data from a second worksheet which causes flickering.

Is there a way to prevent the screen from updating/flickering with SheetB briefly when it gets activated in this macro?

```
Sub ActivateSheetB()

    Application.EnableEvents = False 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheets("SheetB").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: That is why one should avoid using `.Activate` except when the actually want to see the page.  If you are activating the sheet so you can do things with code on that sheet then do not activate it just do what you want referencing properly the sheet.

Comment: I hope it doesn't come to that because there are many hundreds, maybe even thousands of references to activating different sheets, doing some programming, and returning back to where they started in the Excel 2010 system I'm working in.

Comment: if you have many `.Activate` and `.Select` your code is unnecessarily being slowed down.

Comment: It's probably slower but not noticeably. The noticeable part is the screen flickering.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same thing happen to me forever and it's fairly annoying but from my own observation, I believe that application.screenupdating = false is still working. What I mean by that is your code is still being sped up. Other than it visually being annoying and making users think they broke excel this is still an effective method for speeding up your workbook even when switching between sheets.

Hopefully someone comes along with a better answer than mine because I'd love to know what that answer is as well xD

Comment: using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to speed up the code means that one using too many sheet references.  By using memory arrays and limiting the number of times one references the worksheet will speed up the code.  Turning off the screen updating is more a band-aid than the cure.

Comment: ["The premise behind the code is that there is a common set of operations that you can do to "speed up" code. In fact, this is *never* true. In reality, you are turning off Excel functionality that can *slow down* code. There's a big difference."](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158080/36565)