# Scraping web with url in milliseconds Unix

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

The web in which I browse has several pages. I want to click on those elements or play with urls and thus be able to copy the data. The initial URL ends at = 1 & playerType = ALL & ts = 1558502019375, in my code there is a loop that is supposed to go page after page to get the data but I can not get it done.

````
Sub UPDATE_DATA_MLB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim EstaPagina As Byte
Dim EstaURL As String


'Página inicial

EstaPagina = 1
'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
y = 1

EstaURL = "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&playerType=ALL&ts=1558502019375" '&ts=1526432697176"

'start a new browser instance
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'make browser visible
objIE.Visible = False

Do Until EstaPagina = 255
  'navigate to page with needed data
  objIE.navigate EstaURL & EstaPagina
  'wait for page to load
  Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'If UCase(Left(EstaURL, 211) & "1") = UCase(Left(objIE.LocationURL, (211 + Len(EstaPagina)))) And y > 1 Then Exit Do

  'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
  'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable
  For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("datagrid").getElementsByTagName("tr")
      'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
      'Debug.Print ele.textContent

      'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
      'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
      'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
      'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
      'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(5).textContent
      'put text of 4th 'td' in col f
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y).Value = ele.Children(22).textContent
      'increment row counter by 1
      y = y + 1
  Next
EstaPagina = EstaPagina + 1
Loop
lobjIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
Set ele = Nothing

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), _
  Header:=xlNo


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Volcado terminado", vbInformation
Range("A1").Select

  'save the Excel workbook
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661787/application-screenupdating-false-not-working-switching-between-excel-sheets-or)?

Comment: What does _cannot get it done_ mean? Is it looping pages but not extracting info? Failing to loop pages?

Comment: Unable to turn the pages, Failing to loop pages

Comment: I need you to go you are on page 1 Up to 26

Comment: The last code is Internet Explorer correct changes the pages but not the copies in the sheet that I need. How can I complement your code with mine? in this new code does not indicate that descrague the data to the sheet 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XMLHTTP:

The page does ajax calls to get json which it uses to update the content for each page. It does this using query string parameters, one of which is the records per page (default 50). You can view this activity in the browser network tab via dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

You can avoid using a browser and issue xmlhttp requests to the same endpoint, altering the query string parameters to get all the results. It seems, in my testing, you cannot request all the results in one go. Instead, I issue a request for 1000 results, then check if there are any additional results to obtain and issue further requests, in batches of 1000, to get them.

I am using [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the json. I extract the info from the json and load into an array, `results`, so I can write all results out to the sheet in one go - much more efficient this way as reduces i/o with sheet.

After copying the code from the link above into a module called jsonConverter, you need to go  'VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

---

**TODO:**

1. Add error handling for failed request

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub GetResults()
    'VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim ws As Worksheet, results(), i As Long, totalResults As Long
    Dim headers(), columnCount As Long, pageNumber As Long
    Dim numberOfPages As Long, resultsPerPage As Long, json As Object

    resultsPerPage = 1000
    pageNumber = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        .Open "GET", "http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2018&sort_order=%27desc%27&sort_column=%27avg%27&stat_type=hitting&page_type=SortablePlayer&game_type=%27R%27&player_pool=ALL&season_type=ANY&sport_code=%27mlb%27&results=" & resultsPerPage & "&recSP=" & pageNumber & "&recPP=" & resultsPerPage, False
        .send

        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        totalResults = json("stats_sortable_player")("queryResults")("totalSize")
        headers = json("stats_sortable_player")("queryResults")("row").item(1).keys
        numberOfPages = json("stats_sortable_player")("queryResults")("totalP")
        columnCount = UBound(headers) + 1

        ReDim results(1 To totalResults, 1 To columnCount)
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, dict As Object, key As Variant

        For pageNumber = 1 To numberOfPages
            If pageNumber > 1 Then
                .Open "GET", "http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2018&sort_order=%27desc%27&sort_column=%27avg%27&stat_type=hitting&page_type=SortablePlayer&game_type=%27R%27&player_pool=ALL&season_type=ANY&sport_code=%27mlb%27&results=" & resultsPerPage & "&recSP=" & pageNumber & "&recPP=" & resultsPerPage, False
                .send
                Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            End If

            For Each dict In json("stats_sortable_player")("queryResults")("row")
                r = r + 1: c = 1
                For Each key In dict.keys
                    results(r, c) = dict(key)
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, columnCount) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Sample of output ( appreciate can't really read as is - but idea of layout):**

[image]

image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiDTP.png

---

### Internet Explorer:

If you want to use slower browser solution you can concatenate the page number into the url and loop to cover all pages. The number of pages can be extracted from the pagination on page 1.

You can see how to write the tables out below each other by looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135557/6241235). Change the lines with `GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2` to `GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1`

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls

    Public Sub GetData()
        Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, numberOfPages As Long
        Dim url As String, i As Long
        Const PLAYERS_PER_PAGE = 50
        url = "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&playerType=ALL&ts="

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate2 url
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            With .document

                numberOfPages = CLng(.querySelector(".paginationWidget-last").innerText)

                'do something  with page 1
                If numberOfPages > 1 Then

                    For i = 2 To numberOfPages
                        ie.Navigate2 Replace$(url, "page=1", "page=" & CStr(i))
                        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

                        'do something with other pages
                    Next
                    Stop 'delete me later
                End If  
            End With  
            .Quit
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add you sheet into the code and write the values to that sheet. My preference is the top version and you just change sheet1 to your sheet.

Comment: that's the detail I'm new to vba and I do not know at what moment of the code devo add the sheet, please explain if it is in your possibilities distinguished sir.

Comment: in his new code was left mine and I do not know how I can complement it. all the variables are different from my code

Comment: my code writes to sheet 1 as does yours. What is the problem?

Comment: do not keep the data in the sheet, use the last code you wrote and only do the loop between the pages but do not throw any data in the sheet

Comment: yes because I expect you to be able to do that part. My code at the bottom was to help you loop all pages.

Comment: I copied his code in a new module but he does not save the data

Comment: Try the top version and install jsonconverter.bas

Comment: you can download workbook and run: https://tmpfiles.org/download/19133/Book1.xlsb

Comment: I do not know how to complement the codes, this is a personal project, I really need help, I know that this is a website for developers and that I am a nobato but it is very important for me to complete this code

Comment: you are a genius, bless you and yours, let me tell you that I am your admirer from now on and that I will do everything in my power to learn from you all

Comment: The first code works perfectly although the second one shows error.
I am eternally grateful to you, your help to the pending and without asking for anything in return I really appreciate you I am happy

Comment: The second one is fine but you need to add a reference to Microsoft Internet Explorerand add in the extra code to write out the tables. Everything you need is in the answers. The top answer does everything for you. The bottom answer requires you to do a little work using the link I include.

Comment: I hope that the future readers will realize the genius that you are, I have seen your answers in many questions and all very well asked, finally since you tell me how to learn part of what you already know, some advice

Comment: what would you like to know?

Comment: where he got so much knowledge, some guide that I can recommend

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/WiseOwlTutorials/search?query=web-scraping   and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors  and  https://flukeout.github.io/  and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+and+web-scraping

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I do not know how to manage the url from which the data is extracted to this URL " http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2018&sort_order=%27desc%27&sort_column= % 27avg% 27 & stat_type = hitting & page_type = SortablePlayer & game_type =% 27R% 27 & player_pool = ALL & season_type = ANY & sport_code =% 27mlb% 27 & results "

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to complement his second code with mine, although I have not been very professional, I am interested in how to achieve combertir the url of "[official page](http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&playerType=ALL&ts)" to this "[official page for jsone](http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2018&sort_order=%27desc%27&sort_column=%27avg%27&stat_type=hitting&page_type=SortablePlayer&game_type=%27R%27&player_pool=ALL&season_type=ANY&sport_code=%27mlb%27&results)"

```
 Option Explicit
   'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls

Public Sub GetData()

Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim EstaPagina As Byte
EstaPagina = 1
'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
y = 1
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, numberOfPages As Long
Dim url As String, i As Long
Const PLAYERS_PER_PAGE = 50
url = "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+pitching&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=pitching&page=1&playerType=ALL&ts="

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate2 url
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            With .document
                numberOfPages = CLng(.querySelector(".paginationWidget-last").innerText)

                'do something  with page 1
                If numberOfPages > 1 Then

                    For i = 1 To numberOfPages
                        ie.Navigate2 Replace$(url, "page=1", "page=" & CStr(i))

                        For Each ele In ie.document.getElementById("datagrid").getElementsByTagName("tr")
        'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
        'Debug.Print ele.textContent

        'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
        'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).value = ele.Children(1).textContent
        'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).value = ele.Children(2).textContent
        'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).value = ele.Children(3).textContent
        'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).value = ele.Children(4).textContent
        'put text of 4th 'td' in col f
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y).value = ele.Children(5).textContent
        'increment row counter by 1
        y = y + 1
        Next
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
  ' do something with other pages
                    Next
   ' Stop 'delete me later
                End If
            End With
            .Quit
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
    header:=xlNo

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Volcado terminado", vbInformation
Range("A1").Select

    'save the Excel workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save


    End Sub
```